# Increase vlookup cell reference when another value changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have a vlookup which I'd like to only increment the cell reference when the value next to the cell changes, for example:

Source Data:

**Names**

```
Jane
John
Sally
```

Destination Table

**Index Names**

```
1 Jane
1 Jane
1 Jane
2 John
2 John
3 Sally
3 Sally
3 Sally
```

I want to populate the names in the destination table something like:

`=IF(A1=A2,sourceA1,sourceA2)`

except the `sourceA2` reference will only increment when the index changes.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: So the 1, 2, 3, etc. are hard-coded (or result of other formula), and you want to put the corresponding value of Names next to the number?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it. It's not really names, but that seemed the simplest way to explain it. I feel I need to store the value for sourceA2 and increment occassionally but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: You can just use the `INDEX` formula (see my answer), if the 1, and 2 etc. correspond with the place in the source data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your `Source` worksheet

[image]

And this is your `Destination` worksheet

[image]

Use this formula in column B of your `Destination` worksheet

```
=INDEX(Source!A:A;Destination!A:A + 1)  'Added +1 because of the header
```

to get the following result

[image]

Comment: @JoeC Just as a FYI (and for others who would consider using this technique), please note that `OFFSET` is (i) a volatile Excel function and (ii) approx. 2x slower than `INDEX`. This makes of course no difference for a small Workbook, but for larger Workbooks with many formulas, the performance degradation becomes noticeable.

Comment: @PeterK. Good point! Changed it into a non-volatile `INDEX` function.

Comment: Thanks Peter, good to know. Interestingly the index wasn't an index to begin with, but I didn't need the original values, just to keep the rows in groups for reassignment, so a happy coincidence that I used numbers for it.

Comment: @JoeC Well, the fact you used a sequential index simplifies the formula. If you would have used something else (random string), it would still have been easy if you would have an index to match the random string with the corresponding name. Without such an index, you would have to use helper columns.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your exemple, the following formula will work:
`=INDEX(names,A1,)`

Assuming `names` is a defined name of the source data. You of course also can just put the corresponding range here, e.g. `$D1$D3`.
`INDEX` will take the row that is specified in `A1` from the range (`names` in the example), and as there is only one column, you do not need to specify the column, so I left this empty, but you also can put `1`.